# Data from AWK into an array

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I've been looking into sorting an input txt file in unix but have run into some issues I'd love some advice on.

```
Product,color,stock
apple,red,400
apple,green,400
apple,yellow,400
grape,purple,500
banana,yellow,120
```

Say this is my input file. It's just a text file but I want to consolidate my information a bit.

I first used awk to group my products together like so...

```
awk -F '[,]' 'NR >= 1 {b[$1];}
```

This would leave me with the following if I printed it out...

```
apple
grape
banana
```

but if I wanted to include other information such as all the colors of product listed in that row I ran into problems. If I wanted that 'b' index data to go into another array how would I do that (since I can't seem to access 'b' from outside the awk code)? figured the following would work but no luck.

```
awk -F '[,]' 'NR >= 1 {b[$1];}END{for (i in b) productArray+=(b[i])}'
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that sample input. wrt `I can't seem to access 'b' from outside the awk code` - well, no, of course you can't, when have you ever been able to access the value of a variable used in a C or any other program outside of that program? awk is not shell it's a tool you call from shell just like a C program would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk doesn't really have nested lists like that.  If you want the data to go into a different array (the array `j`),  then you can do this:

`cat test.txt |awk -F '[,]' 'NR > 1 { b[$1]=$2} END {for (x in b) { j[x]; print x}}'`

If you want to the second column collapsed into unique lines based on column 1,  you might do something like this:

`$ cat test.txt |awk -F ',' 'NR > 1 { if ($1 in b) { b[$1] = b[$1] FS $2} else { b[$1]=$2}} END {for (x in b) { print x,": " b[x] }}'
apple : red,green,yellow
banana : yellow
grape : purple`

Comment: That second code works great! Little unsure of how it works though. I see how it is checking the 'product' to see if it already exists in b but I am unsure of the particulars after that. Especially where you have b[$1]=$2] for the initial product; is what I had (just b[$1]) not proper?

Comment: `b[$1]=$2` means setting the string from the second field ($2) as the value of `b[$1]` ie. `product apple is red`, on the next record `product apple is red, green` etc.

Comment: Google UUOC and `if ($1 in b) { b[$1] = b[$1] FS $2} else { b[$1]=$2}` is more commonly/idiomatically written `b[$1] = ($1 in b ? b[$1] FS : "") $2`. Also, if you add `-v OFS=' : '` then the print at the end becomes just `print x, b[x]`.